# Joining Same Table Twice

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have read all the other posts on this question and have incorporated the advice, but am still getting runtime error 3075: (Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression).  Here is my query:

```
SELECT Patient.FirstName, pE.ID, cE.ID FROM Patient 
    LEFT JOIN EMailAddress AS pE 
              ON Patient.idEMailAddress = pE.ID 
    LEFT JOIN EMailAddress AS cE 
              ON Patient.idReminderEmailCustomEmail = cE.ID
```

Comment: Do you need the table name in the SELECT since you did not give the table an alias name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access requires parentheses in nested `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT Patient.FirstName, pE.ID, cE.ID 
FROM (Patient 
LEFT JOIN EMailAddress AS pE 
          ON Patient.idEMailAddress = pE.ID)
LEFT JOIN EMailAddress AS cE 
          ON Patient.idReminderEmailCustomEmail = cE.ID
```